# RubyやRailsのコーディングチェックツールを探しています

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails

C#やPerlを使っていた頃はStyleCop, FxCop, Perl::Critic, Perltidy等でコードを自動的にチェックしていました。

RubyやRailsでも同じようなツールはありますか？

Googleで検索してみましたが、これというツールが見つかりませんでした。

---

注：この質問は過去に英語版に投稿した質問を転記したものです。 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9103874/coding-style-checker-or-code-formatter-for-ruby-rails

Answer (score 29):

[RuboCop](https://github.com/bbatsov/rubocop) がオススメです。Rails に特化したチェッカもついています。

Comment: どういうことができるツールか、どのあたりがおすすめかを書いておくと、読者の判断材料になり、より役に立つ回答になると思います

Answer (score 7):

Railsらしいコードかどうかは、[railsbp/rails_best_practices](https://github.com/railsbp/rails_best_practices)というgemを使うとチェックできます。

Answer (score 6):

IDEであるIntelliJ(RubyMine)を使えば、コーディングスタイルについての問題をエディタ上で確認できます。

Answer (score 4):

GitHub 上のプロジェクトであれば、[HoundCI](https://houndci.com/) が手軽です。普通に Pull Request を出すと、コーディングスタイル上の問題点を以下のように GitHub 上でコメントとして残してくれます。

[image: HoundCI のコメント]

HoundCI はスタイルチェッカーとして [RuboCop](https://github.com/bbatsov/rubocop) を使っています。ですので、チェック項目は基本的に RuboCop と同じです。

注意点があるとすれば、HoundCI のコーディング規約が RuboCop のデフォルト設定と多少異なることです。たとえば:

- RuboCop: `"foobar"` のような式展開のない文字列は `'foobar'` と書かせる。
- HoundCI: 文字列内にシングルクオートがなければ `"foobar"` と書かせる。

これは、HoundCI を提供する [thoughtbot](http://thoughtbot.com/) のコーディング規約だそうです。

Answer (score 2):

オンラインのサービスに登録すると、単純な書式に限らないコードのチェックとレポート作成を自動的に行なってくれるものがあります。
内部的にはRubocopなども使われていますが、セットアップが要らないので手軽です。

- https://codeclimate.com/
- https://scrutinizer-ci.com/

Answer (score 1):

sideCIというgemが古くなっていないか、セキュリティチェック、Rails-best-practiceをチェックしてくれるサービスが有ります。
Github連携してくれるのでPullreqのタイミングで見てくれますね。今のところ無料です。

またrubocop-gitという修正したところだけRubocopチェックしてくれるgemがお勧めです

Answer (score 1):

guardとか使うとリアルタイムに実行エラー拾えたりもしますよー。もちろんsyntaxもです。
ネットで参考にさせていただいた記事を張っておきます。

[Guard gem を利用してファイルの変更を検出し、任意のタスクを自動実行する](http://qiita.com/tbpgr/items/f5be21d8e19dd852d9b7)